# React-Native android: Debugging options?

Tags: remote-debugging, react-native

I keep receiving a 401 unauthorised response from my android application. When I use the remote debugging from the emulator I am unable to view the network requests.

Is it possible to view network requests from the emulator's remote debugger? If not what options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

For Android you can execute in console this `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`.

This is the doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html.

Comment: Thanks for the help Carlos but I am looking to be able to view my network requests and not just the network response.